# Firefox OS: How launch an APP in code

Tags: firefox-os

I want to open an APP when one Alarm is fired. I can fire alarms with Alarm API, but I don't know how I can open the APP when the alarm is fired. Now, when the alarm is fired the APP is opened but in background.

I have Firefox OS 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only app you want to launch is your app from inside your app then you can use [Open Web Apps API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/JavaScript_API) and write code like the following:

```
var request = window.navigator.mozApps.getSelf();
request.onsuccess = function() {
  if (request.result) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      request.result.launch();
    }, 10000);
  } else {
    alert("Called from outside of an app");
  }
};
request.onerror = function() {
  alert("Error: " + request.error.name);
};
```

The above example will launch (bring in foreground) your App after 10 seconds.

request.result is an [App object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/App) which describes your app.

---

In case you want to launch other apps, you have to use [mozApps.mgmt.getAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Apps.mgmt.getAll) to find other apps (it returns as request.result an array of installed apps - [App objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/App)). To use this API your app should be a [privileged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Packaged_apps) one. For code examples check at [gaia source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/gaia/search?string=mozApps.mgmt.getAll&find=&findi=&filter=%5E%5B%5E%5C0%5D%2a%24&hitlimit=&tree=gaia) which you can find also on [github](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/).

disclaimer: In some cases mozApps.mgmt methods needs your app to be certified, I am not 100% sure if this happens with mozApps.mgmt.getAll(). If someone knows please edit my answer or leave a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can launch any app, like this:

```
let request = navigator.mozApps.mgmt.getAll();

request.onsuccess = function() {
  let apps = request.result;
  apps.forEach(function iterateApp(app) {
    if (app.origin != "origin of the app you want to launch") return;
    app.launch();
  });
};

request.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Error: " + request.error.name);
};
```

Here, 'navigator.mozApps.mgmt.getAll()' returns '**pendingGetAll**' object. Inside onsuccess, **pendingGetAll.result**(here request.result) will be an array of App objects that contains all the apps installed in the current browser or KaiOS phone.

example of app origin: app://contacts.lic.com.
You will get it inside the manifest file of the app(manifest.webapp).

Comment: Just add these 2 things inside the manifest file:
  "type": "certified",
  "permissions": {
    "webapps-manage": {}
  }

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [MozActivity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozActivity) to open another app, please reference camera and gallery apps. in [camera.js:775-789](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/v1-train/apps/camera/js/camera.js#L775-L789) it use MozActivity to open Gallery:

```js
var a = new MozActivity({
  name: 'browse',
  data: {
    type: 'photos'
  }
});
```

and you need to add avtivities in manifest.webapp for your app:

```js
"activities": {
  "browse": {
    "filters": {
      "type": "photos"
     },
    "disposition": "window"
  },
  ...
}
```

there is a sample to open gallery in an app:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6aEC/

and you also can open this link in your firefox os phone, install and test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6aEC/fxos.html